# How to view exact image dimensions of a media in Admin view?

Tags: attachments, images, thumbnails

I know programmatically we can see the attachment sizes in templates, but I'm looking for a way to see the precise dimensions of the resized medium, large, xlarge sizes too. No plugin seems to do this, and WP even in v5.x (latest at this time) does not seem to have any intelligent ways to explore the precise sizes! Welcome any pointers, thank you!

Comment: In what context? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am in the admin screen of Wordpress. I click on "Media" and view my images. For each image, I'd like to see the exact dimensions of all its sizes right there, visually: the thumbnail is 150x150, the "medium" is 300x??, the "large" is 768x??...etc.

Comment: So I take it this isn't possible. Which is quite a sad miss. All other CMSes I know have this basic feature.